# Coding a Quine in J

Tags: j, quine

Am I missing some key part in the definition of a quine, because this seems far too easy to be considered even worthwhile in J.

> NB. commentary for Quine code
>
> verbatim =: (3 : 0)''
>
> smoutput 1!:1 <'filename' NB. where 'filename' would obviously be the pathway to the script file
>
> )

This seems to do exactly what the definition of a quine is: outputting the source code of the action. Is this it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're missing part of the normal definition.  A quine should do no input.  I think this is precisely to disallow this trick.

There are some J quines on [the J wiki](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Puzzles/Quine).